# How to embed text view inside a table view cell having multiple sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textview

I am using a table view with multiple section. In one table view cell which is having text label and detailed text label to display array objects. Now I want add a new section, in this section I will be having more text like a paragraph. How to display data in text view?

```
{
var dataSection01:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var dataSection02:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var sectionTitleArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var arrayForBool : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var sectionContentDict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

in viewDidLoad()
sectionTitleArray = ["Assignment Information","Details"]
let tmp1 : NSArray = assignInfoArray
var string1 = sectionTitleArray .objectAtIndex(0) as? String
[sectionContentDict .setValue(tmp1, forKey:string1! )]
let tmp2 : NSArray = detailsInfoArray
string1 = sectionTitleArray .objectAtIndex(1) as? String
[sectionContentDict .setValue(tmp2, forKey:string1! )]

dataSection01 = [ "Name:", "Phone", "Email" so on]
dataSection02 = [ "Address", "Street", "State","ZipCode"]

//mapping like this using object mapper
assignInfoArray.addObject((newDetails?.clientName)!)
assignInfoArray.addObject((newDetails?.clientPhone)!)


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionTitleArray.count
}
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{



    let CellIdentifier = "CellRightDetail"
    var cell :UITableViewCell?
    cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: "CellRightDetail")
    }
    let manyCells : Bool = arrayForBool .objectAtIndex(indexPath.section).boolValue

    if (!manyCells) {
        //  cell.textLabel.text = @"click to enlarge";
    }
    else{
        let items: NSMutableArray = self.dataFromIndexPath(indexPath)

        let content = sectionContentDict .valueForKey(sectionTitleArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as! String) as! NSArray
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = content .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Bold", size: 13.0) 
        cell!.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row] as? String

    }

    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    if(arrayForBool .objectAtIndex(section).boolValue == true)
    {
        let tps = sectionTitleArray.objectAtIndex(section) as! String
        let count1 = (sectionContentDict.valueForKey(tps)) as! NSArray
        return count1.count
    }
    return 0;
}
func dataFromIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSMutableArray!
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        return dataSection01
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        return dataSection02
    }

    return nil
}

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a imagine that shows what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Ajay_Ajju, you should edit your question, show more information to us, your question is not clear, show your code.

Comment: I think creating CustomTableViewCell is good answer

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski Obviously `Customcell` is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In storyboard**
Blue color is the first cell and green color is my second cell.

[image]

You have to create two cell like this and for each cell you have to create different customcell class. Make outlets of `UILabel` and `UITextView` in their respective class and use the below code .
May be your requirement vary little bit, so use delegates  according to it.

**Implement your code like this:**

```
// MARK:- --- TableView Height ---

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return 45
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return 1
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
    }

     open func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 2
    }

    // MARK:- --- TableView tittle ---
     open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

        return "hearder " + String(section)
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{

        let viewHeader : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 64, width: self.view.frame.size.width , height: 45))
        viewHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 180.0/255.0, green: 160.0/255.0, blue: 240.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        let btnHeader : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: viewHeader.frame.size.width , height: viewHeader.frame.size.height))
        btnHeader.setTitle("section #\(section)", for: UIControlState())
        btnHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        btnHeader.isSelected = arrIsExpand[section]
        btnHeader.tag = section
        btnHeader.addTarget(self, action:#selector(expandMethod(_:)) , for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        viewHeader.addSubview(btnHeader)

        return viewHeader

    }

    // MARK:- --- TableView data source ---
    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
          return 10

    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        if(indexPath.section == 0){ // for your first section
            let firstCell : MyFirstCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstcell") as! DesignTableCell
            firstCell.lblTittle?.text = "Tittle"
            firstCell.lblDescription?.text = "Description"
             return firstCell
        }
            //for second section
        else{
            let secondCell : MySecondCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondcell") as! DesignTableCell
            secondCell.lblTittle?.text = "Tittle"
            secondCell.txtViewData?.text = "Blah! Blah!"
            return secondCell
        }
    }
```

May be you face the  problem with the row height because I give static height here i.e. 45, so use `uiautomaticdimension` instead of static 45, and also impliment the delegate `estimatedHeightForRow`.